# npm run dev execution webpack error, My webpack is newly installed

Tags: javascript

My webpack is just installed, the following is my project environment:
[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
    // 打包模式
    mode: "development",
    // 打包入口文件
    entry: path.join(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    output: {
        // 输出文件路径
        path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        // 输出文件名称
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test_webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

Execute `npm run dev`, Output the following

```
λ npm run dev

> test_webpack@1.0.0 dev D:\WWW\test_webpack
> webpack



#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000A5D21ECF70npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! test_webpack@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test_webpack@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-19T07_20_00_087Z-debug.log
```

**C:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-19T07_20_00_087Z-debug.log**:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~predev: test_webpack@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~dev: test_webpack@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~dev: PATH: D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\WWW\test_webpack\node_modules\.bin;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\bin;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\vendor\bin;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Tencent\QQ\Bin;D:\Program Files\PremiumSoft\Navicat Premium 12;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\ffmpeg\bin;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\nvm;D:\Program Files\nodejs;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\cangs\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.2.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.4\bin;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\nvm;D:\Program Files\nodejs;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\cmd;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\mingw64\bin;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin;D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\cmder
9 verbose lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~dev: CWD: D:\WWW\test_webpack
10 silly lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack' ]
11 silly lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle test_webpack@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: test_webpack@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Users\cangs\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid test_webpack@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd D:\WWW\test_webpack
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error test_webpack@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the test_webpack@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

But execute `node_modules/.bin/webpack` is allowed

```
λ node_modules\.bin\webpack


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000A3F1AFD030
```

I can't know the way to solve the error from the error message output. I hope that more experienced people can help me.

Comment: "test: echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"  This line might be causing the error. Try replacing it with test: jest or test:mocha

Comment: I deleted the test in scripts, but the same error still occurs.

Comment: don't delete the test, just replace it's value with "test" : "jest". If you don't have a test runner, run "npm i jest" first

Comment: I modified test to "test": "echo \"jest\"" ,Then run npm run test without problems, But the same error still occurs when executing npm run dev

Comment: Try this - delete node_modules and package.lock.json and then npm install and then npm run dev